# Refreshing OAuth2 tokens in async JS

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0

I have a single page app that talks to an API. I own both parts (the API and the single page app aka "official client"). The client is javascript, so asynchronous.

The problem I have is when the token expires, due to async nature of Javascript.

The implementation of OAuth2 that I use will immediately revoke all previous access tokens, when a refresh token is used (this is fine according to OAuth2 specifications).

Because of this, I do not know how to refresh the token in JS without potentially encountering a scenario where 2 async requests keep revoking each other's token. Or one async request revoking the access token another request was just about to use to make a request.

How do you guys solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Found out myself, this works for me (CoffeeScript, Object.clone is from Sugar.JS):

```
  tokenReloadPromise = null

  $.ajaxPrefilter (options, userOptions, xhr)=>
      if tokenReloadPromise?
        xhr.abort()
        tokenReloadPromise.then ->
          options.noTokenRefresh = true
          $.ajax(options)
      else
        originalOptions = Object.clone(options)
        # configure access token for request here
        unless options.noTokenRefresh == true
          options.error = (xhr)->
            if xhr.status == 401
              tokenReloadPromise ?= new jQuery.Deferred
              tokenReloadPromise.then ->
                originalOptions.noTokenRefresh = true
                $.ajax(originalOptions)
              App.execute "refresh:access_token", ->
                promise = tokenReloadPromise
                tokenReloadPromise = null
                promise.resolve()
            else
              originalOptions.error.apply(this, arguments)
    true
```